# Remove anti-aliasing for pandas plot.area

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot stacked areas with Python, and find out this Pandas' function:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.plot.area();
```

However, the result is weirdly antialiased, mixing together the colors, as shown on those 2 plots:
[image: Example of plot.area]

[image: Zoom of plot.area]

The same problem occurs in the example provided in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#area-plot).

Do you know how to remove this anti-aliasing? (Or another mean to get a neat output for stacked representation of line plots.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a matplotlib stack plot works fine

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
ax.stackplot(df.index, df.values.T)
```

[image]

Since the area plot is a stackplot, the only difference would be the linewidth of the areas, which you can set to zero.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df.plot.area(linewidth=0)
```

[image]

The remaining grayish lines are then indeed due to antialiasing. You may turn that off in the matplotlib plot

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.stackplot(df.index, df.values.T, antialiased=False)
```

The result however, may not be visually appealing:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there are two boundaries.
Try a zero line width:

```
df.plot.area(lw=0);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it is much better with this option! To go further, do you know how to remove the subtle gray lines remaining between the stacked areas?